# Integration with Active Directory

Tags: oauth, active-directory, single-sign-on, openid, adfs

I have a local user management system. Recently I launched new and fresh Active Directory server and some of Windows based services connected to it, such as RDS, Exchange server and....

I want to connect my Active Directory server to my local user management system that can authenticate users and login to have access to services such as RDWeb.
I don't know what should I do and where should I start.

Could you please help me and give me some examples?

I installed ADFS already.

Comment: What is your local user management system? If this is your own custom software, implement LDAP to connect to Active Directory.

Comment: The local user management system is some self deployed system that developed with mysql and php. The point is that Active Directory need to get authentication through the local user management and I don't have any idea how to deploy it.

Comment: Is your goal to authenticate your AD users in your custom system (meaning which direction)? ADFS is very complicated to implement. It would be easier to use LDAP and keep both systems duplicating the same users. In this case your custom system would connect to AD via LDAP and update itself with the current user list. This is not ideal and does have problems such as password synchronization. Another method would be to update your custom system to just use AD for authentication.

Comment: My goal is vice versa, I want to authenticate the users that I have in local user management system with my AD. I have some local user management system(such as Wordpress user system) that have around 1000 users. I want to connect it with AD. So when my users want to login to their windows in my network, they'll authenticate through my local user management system and login to windows operating system. I know it should be done by AD, but I don't know how can I connect it to my local user management system.

Comment: You will need to implement Kerberos and SPNEGO. Start here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_Windows_Authentication